# Need help sorting data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I have a list of values that I need to have the query sort in a specific order.

ID | VALUE | 
1    AA 
1    OUT 
2    OUT 
2    OUT 
3    AA 
3    OUT 
4    CC 
4    OUT 
4    OUT 
5    CC 
5    OUT 
6    AA 
6    OUT 
7    CC 
7    OUT 
8    OUT 
8    BB

I need the above to sort like this:

ID | VALUE |  
1    AA 
1    OUT 
3    AA 
3    OUT 
6    AA 
6    OUT 
8    BB 
8    OUT 
4    CC 
4    OUT 
4    OUT 
5    CC 
5    OUT 
7    CC 
7    OUT 
2    OUT 
2    OUT

Any ideas on the best way to do this in SQL?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: What is the logic for the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by max(case when value <> 'OUT' then value end) over (partition by id),
         value
```

Comment: order by max(case when value <> 'OUT' then value end) over (partition by id) this worked great thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just putting another idea:

```
Order by id, 
         case when value <> 'OUT' then value end
```

Cheers!!